# What should be the schema for this xml?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to write XSD schema for the following XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<locs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="loc.xsd">
    <loc required="true"  comment="A comment">ABC</loc>
</locs>
```

The rules I am trying to enforce these rules in the schema:

1. root element `locs` must have 1 or more elements of `loc`
2. `loc` must have 2 attributes: `required` is a `boolean` & `comment` is a `string`,of non-zero length, not composed entirely of white space and/or punctuation marks
3. `loc` must have a string value, of non-zero length, not composed entirely of white space and/or punctuation marks

I've got this far with my `loc.xsd` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="locs">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="loc" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:complexContent>
                            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                <xs:attribute name="required" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="comment" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:complexContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

With this I am able to enforce rules 1 & 2 but, the 3rd rule is not being enforced, so an entry like the following is valid:

```
<loc required="false"  comment="Another comment"/>
```

What am I missing? I've spent few hours already on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close.

You say the third constraint is not being enforced, but the example you show doesn't illustrate non-enforcement:  the element

```
<loc required="false"  comment="Another comment"/>
```

has a zero-length string as content.  You told the XSD validator that that was OK, when you said the type of loc was an extension of xs:string.

The approach you need to take is illustrated by Jirka Š.'s answer.  If you are happy with any non-empty string, you can adopt that solution verbatim.  But before you do, be sure you are willing to accept instances like this one:

```
<loc required="false"  comment="&#x9; ">  </loc>
```

If you're not, then your requirement is not that comment and loc should have string values, and also not that they should have non-empty string values, but something more stringent.  Ideally, of course,  you want them to have *useful*, *sensible* values, but it may not be possible to define the set of useful comments or the set of useful loc values formally.  Some people settle for saying they want a non-empty string which is not composed entirely of white space and punctuation marks (so it has at least one character matching the class `\w`).

```
<xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyNonWSString">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1" />
    <xs:pattern value="(\W)*\w(\W|\w)*"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: You made a good point with white spaces! I improved my definition to take care on it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one - it could work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1" />
            <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:complexType name="loc_type">
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="nonEmptyString">
                <xs:attribute name="required" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="comment" type="nonEmptyString" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="locs">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="loc" type="loc_type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for your answers, wish I could accept both of them! Here is what I finally adopted (also modified the question to remove confusions):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!-- Must be a string of non-zero length, not composed entirely of whitespace and punctuation marks -->
    <xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
            <xs:pattern value="(\W)*\w(\W|\w)*"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="locs">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="loc" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                            <xs:extension base="nonEmptyString">
                                <xs:attribute name="required" type="xs:boolean" use="required"/>
                                <xs:attribute name="comment" type="nonEmptyString" use="required"/>
                            </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```